# Smart Pointers for Binary Tree

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

If I have a binary tree where each node contain just pointers to children nodes, then `unique_ptr` works very well. If I want each node to have a parent pointer, then the situation is not so nice, since a node may have three pointers pointing to it: [Binary Tree with parent pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inzfI.jpg)

What can I do in this instance? I can use `shared_ptr` for everything, but I've been told it's not a good design since I may get cycles. If I were to use a `weak_ptr` for the parent pointer, which `shared_ptr` do I create this `weak_ptr` from?

Which types of pointers would be a good fit for a binary tree?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a pair of `std::unique_ptr`'s and a **non-owning** raw pointer to the parent.

Comment: Most of the time you should not see the smart pointers a simple self-deleting pointers, but instead as an ownership primitive. Can a "resource" have only a single owner (with `std::unique_ptr`) or multiple simultaneous owners (with `std::shared_ptr`)?

Comment: Maybe I'm alone in here, but the whole idea of using smart pointers inside btree implementation is not the best one. I see no problem in using raw pointers inside a concrete class that you have control over. Also the concept of "being an owner" is not easily (imho there is more then one "intuitive" view) tied to a tree. If you'd want to implement some graph operations over it later, it will probably become a mess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I have a binary tree where each node contain just pointers to
>   children nodes, then `unique_ptr` works very well.

Right.

> If I want each node to have a parent pointer, then the situation is
>   not so nice, since a node may have three pointers pointing to it

You should distinguish pointers between *owning* pointers and *observing* pointers.

Having *raw* *owning* pointers is a bad idea and a source of bugs and leaks; on the other hand, having *raw* *observing* pointers can be fine in many cases (as long as the observed object is still "live").

In your case, you may want to consider a design in which each node contains `unique_ptr`s to children nodes, as these are *owning* pointers, and using a smart owning pointer like `unique_ptr` works well in this case.

On the other hand, the children nodes can refer to their parent using a *non-owning* pointer (the children *"don't own"* their parent, the children nodes just *observe* their parent), and a *raw* pointer works fine as non-owning *observing* pointer.

As a side note, when/if you use `shared_ptr` you have to pay attention to *cycles*, as if you don't properly *break* them, then you have leaks (unreleased objects). On the other hand, the parent pointing to children via owning `unique_ptr`s, and the children *observing* their parent via raw observing pointers, seems a simpler design to me.

Comment: Thanks. I thought built-in pointers were always bad (with the exception of function pointers). But it makes much more sense to think of owning and observing pointers.  Weak pointers and built-in (dumb) pointers should be used for observing. Unique and shared pointers for owning. Thanks a lot, this is much more clear to me.

Comment: @RonnyZed You're welcome. I'm glad I was of some help.

Comment: What are "raw observing pointers"? Just plain old regular pointers with `*` and `&`?

Comment: @Alexander an observing pointer is a concept. A pointer that doesn't own the data it points to. For this you can use raw pointers (e.g. `Node* parent`) hence the "raw observing pointers" nomenclature or you could create your own class that mimics a raw pointer but makes it clear by its type that is just an observer pointer (e.g. `Observing_ptr<Node> parent`) [cont]

Comment: ... [cont] If you application uses smart pointers for ownership and raw pointers for observing pointers then that's ok as it's clear that a raw pointer is an observer and has no ownership semantics. If however your application uses some 3rd party poorly designed library that uses raw pointers for ownership semantics then you might want to create the mentioned `Observer_ptr` class in order to clarify which pointers are just observers.

Comment: A better way is to layout nodes in an adjacency list, deque or vector of unique_ptr, which strongly owns them 1:1, and then use weak_ref or raw pointers to represent edges within each node. No memory leaks will happen because the outer container goes away will all the nodes at once, and no strong components to leak either.

Comment: How would you create such a tree? Typically it would be within a loop, but then the pointers go out of scope immediately, and delete the nodes, right?